# How could I prevent tinyurl(shortened URL) storing in Mysql database with Php

Tags: php, mysql

How could I prevent tinyurl(shortened URL) storing in **Mysql** database with **Php**.

Comment: If I am guessing right your problem. You can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare blacklist of this type of service providers and then validate user input against that list:

```
<?php

$blacklist = array(
    'service_provider',
    'another_service_provider',
    'yet_another'
);

$user_input = 'some text with tinylink another_service_provider/abc123 in the middle';

$user_input_is_valid = true;
foreach ($blacklist as $entry) {
    if (strpos($user_input, $entry) !== false) {
        $user_input_is_valid = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($user_input_is_valid === false) {
    echo 'sorry you can not submit that...' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I think you should add more details for this to be considered an answer. Otherwise , you should probably add a comment.

Comment: More details added